# MATLAB: variable names from array

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables

I want to give a number to a variable, such that name of that variable is the i<sup>th</sup> component of array with variable names. Below is the 
code I want to run, but I can't.

```
varname = {'test1','test2'};
rangenameraw = {'A','B','C'};
rangenamecolstart = {'1','11'};
rangenameend = {'10', '20'};
for i = 1:1:length(varname)
        varname(i) =xlsread(filename, strcat(rangenameraw,rangenamecolstart,':'rangenameraw,rangenameend);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to create variables dynamically which can be achieved using the [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) function of MATLAB.

```
for i = 1:1:length(varname)
        assignin('base', varname{i}, xlsread(filename, strcat(rangenameraw,rangenamecolstart,':'rangenameraw,rangenameend));
end
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why 'base'?

Comment: @Tom... `base` means the scope of the created variable is the main MATLAB workspace. Alternatively, you can specify `caller` which means the variable would be local to the function which calls `assignin`. Check the description of `assignin` in MATLAB documentation.

Comment: thank you. You sing the `base` seems the safest. So, I'll stick with that. Thank you very much!